Is $\operatorname{FinGrp}^{\operatorname{op}}$ a concrete category?
I'm an undergraduate math student currently studying group theory, which I've been loving a lot. Recently I've been reading up on some (very) basic category theory, and in the process I've developed some questions. My understanding is that a concrete category is a category with a faithful functor into the category of sets, which means that in a certain sense a concrete category can be realized as a category of structured sets with morphisms that are functions of sets preserving said structure. Thus in the case of the category FinGrp, the forgetful functor into Set is a faithful functor, so FinGrp is a concrete category. I'm also pretty sure I at least intuitively understand the idea of the opposite category. Which leads me to the question posed in the title. Can we understand the opposite category of the category of finite groups as being some kind of sets with a preserved structure, in the same way we can view the category of finite groups as sets with a preserved structure? If not, how would one show that no such faithful functor exists? Even if the answer to this question might be currently be beyond my understanding, I'd appreciate any direction in getting closer to understanding this. Thank you!

Simply because it's not too big, FinGrp is definitely a concrete (or concretizable - see this old answer of mine re: terminological ambiguity) category. Offhand, though, I don't see a particularly "nice" faithful functor from FinGrp to Set.

This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980933/what-is-the-opposite-category-of-set. You can apply the opposite functor of the forgetful functor $\mathbf{FinGrp} \to \mathbf{Set}$ (or even $\mathbf{FinSet}$) to get a faithful functor $\mathbf{FinGrp}^{\text{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}^{\text{op}}$ or $\mathbf{FinSet}^{\text{op}}$, so the explicit description of $\mathbf{Set}^{\text{op}}$ as a concrete category might be what you need.

To extract a simple answer from CJ's comment:
The functor which sends a finite group $G$ to the set $\mathcal{P}(G)$ of subsets of $G$, and sends a homomorphism $f : G \to H$ to the function $\mathcal{P}(H) \to \mathcal{P}(G)$ defined by $S \mapsto f^{-1}(S)$, is faithful.

Just to clarify something: since the morphisms of $\operatorname{FinGrp}^{\operatorname{op}}$ are the reversed morphisms of $\operatorname{FinGrp}$, are we sending the morphism in $\operatorname{FinGrp}^{\operatorname{op}}$ corresponding to $f$ in $\operatorname{FinGrp}$ to the defined function, or is there something else I'm not understanding? Thank you for your answer!

Yes, that's right.
